# How to directly read an image file from a url address in R

Tags: r, url, jpeg

I'm trying to directly load a .jpeg image from a url address. I'm wondering if there is a basic way to do this by using a `url` connection.

I first tried:

```
require(biOps)
con <- url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Apollonian_spheres.jpg")
pic <- readJpeg(con)
#Error in readJpeg(con) : Cannot open file.
```

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888120/loading-png-files-directly-from-url) seems to be along the same lines, but for a .png file. I tried to adapt to a .jpeg, but also got an error.

```
require(biOps)
require(RCurl)
myurl <- "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Apollonian_spheres.jpg"
pic <-  readJpeg(getURLContent(myurl))
#Error in readJpeg(getURLContent(myurl)) : Cannot open file.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just save the image as a temporary file:

```
myurl <- "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Apollonian_spheres.jpg"
z <- tempfile()
download.file(myurl,z,mode="wb")
pic <- readJPEG(z)
file.remove(z) # cleanup
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Can you also provide a way to then delete the file `z` from within R after loading?

Comment: @Marcinthebox Just added it.

Answer (score 7):

You do NOT have to save the image into the disk. You could directly read the image through the URL as well as below:

```
library(magick)
image_url <- "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Apollonian_spheres.jpg"
pic <- image_read(image_url)
print(pic)
```

[image]