# Issue with reading a PNG from URL and adding element to patchwork plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add an image/logo from a URL to the top corner of my plot which is created with the `patchwork` package. I've tried following the method suggested in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888120/loading-png-files-directly-from-url), but I'm getting an error (displayed below) when using `inset_element()`.

`my_image` is contained as a large array in my environment once I run the `readPNG()` function, and I'm presuming this is where the issues lies. Some assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.0.5
library(patchwork)
library(RCurl)
#> Warning: package 'RCurl' was built under R version 4.0.5
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'RCurl'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     complete

dat <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = 1:10
)

list_of_url_logos <- cfbfastR::cfbd_team_info() %>%
  select(school, logo)

my_url <- head(list_of_url_logos$logo, 1)

my_image <-  png::readPNG(getURLContent(my_url))


p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()

p2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line()

p1 / p2 +
  inset_element(my_image, left = 0.6, bottom = 0.6, right = 1, top = 1, align_to = "full")
#> Error in UseMethod("as_patch"): no applicable method for 'as_patch' applied to an object of class "c('array', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to fix your issue would be to convert your raster image to a grob using `grid::rasterGrob`.

As I wasn't able to run code as I lack the necessary API key for `cfbfastR::cfbd_team_info()` let's first reproduce your issue with the R logo:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(RCurl)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = 1:10
)

myurl <- "https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png"
my_image <-  png::readPNG(getURLContent(myurl))

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()

p2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line()

p1 / p2 +
  inset_element(my_image, left = 0.6, bottom = 0.6, right = 1, top = 1, align_to = "full")
#> Error in UseMethod("as_patch"): no applicable method for 'as_patch' applied to an object of class "c('array', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

Now, converting to a raster grob gives the desired result:

```
p1 / p2 +
  inset_element(grid::rasterGrob(my_image), left = 0.6, bottom = 0.6, right = 1, top = 1, align_to = "full")
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, @stefan! Thanks a lot! I forgot about needing the API key, sorry.